# Recognize handwirte letters with noise of lineate alphabets

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Got a problem when recognizing handwriting letters.

So, below are input images:

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

Third:

[image]

Fourth:

[image]

I use tesseract to recognize letters:

```
tesseract t4.png s -l wni_l --psm 6
```

where wni_l is self trained data:

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B33_p7UnVqoybkdBV2ROU3ZCZk0)

Here is result:

First: AB

Second: AB

Third: AB

Fourth: BDB

My question is, is there anyway to ignore lineate or altered letters?

Maybe need to refine input images by opencv or other machine learning skills, e.g. tensorflow ?

So, for images except the first one, I need to get B instead of those wrong results.

Or maybe force training by adding these guys to negative cases(if use SVM)?

Env:

Python 2.7.10

Tessert: 4.0.0

Opencv: 3.2.0

Any suggestion is great appreciated.

Thanks.

Wesley